# What is the meaning of | in Javascript

Tags: javascript, operators

What does | do in Javascript? Is it similar to the logical or operator `||`? I have seen it being used to apparently convert strings to numbers. How does this work?

```js
var x = '12345';
var num = x|0;
console.log(num);
```

Comment: It's a bitwise OR. `|0` can truncate floating point numbers.

Comment: How many votes does it need to close it as a dup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [bitwise OR `|`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_OR). Sometimes misused (64 bit float vs 32 bit integer) for getting integer values.

```js
var x = '12345.678',
    num = x | 0;

console.log(num);
```

Comment: How does this operator convert Strings to numbers?

Comment: by using a numerical operator, javascript tries to convert the operands to number.

Comment: @Zamboni takes the string, performs bitwise arithmetic on the value of it and it always returns a number.

Comment: @NinaScholz Thank you!